# summing integers in a file in python

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, text-files

I have a file containing a random number of integers, the integers can be seperated by space, tab och by linebreak. i.e
textfile.txt contains

```
12 34 55     22 (tab)
3
5
6
7 13
```

I know how to sum from a file containing only integers seperated by linebreak,

```
f=open('txtfile.txt')
sum = 0
for i in f:
        sum += int(i)
```

and summing from a line (seperated by either space or tab)

```
linesum = 0
aa=f.readline()
bb=aa.split()

for el in bb:
    nr = int(el)
    linesum += nr
```

running this on the first line in textfile.txt returns 123.

What im having trouble with is combining both of these to sum integers seperated by BOTH line breaks and blankspaces and tabs.

What I want the program to do is use the linesum program on lines containing more than 1 integer, else I want to use the linebreak sum program.
However Im having problems generalizing the two for-loops into a program that checks which of the two is to be used.
Any directions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the answer helped you solve your problem, kindly mark it as the right answer, or if any other clarifications are needed, you can comment on the existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module to sum over all the numbers present in the file:

```py
In [1]: import re

In [2]: text = open('input_file.txt').read() # Read from file

In [3]: text
Out[3]: '12 34 55     22 (tab)\n3\n5\n6\n7 13\n'


In [4]: list_numbers = re.findall('\d+', text) # Extract all numbers using the regex '\d+', which matches one, or more consecutive digits

In [5]: list_numbers
Out[5]: ['12', '34', '55', '22', '3', '5', '6', '7', '13']

In [6]: sum([int(number) for number in list_numbers]) # Find the sum of all the numbers
Out[6]: 157
```